# Cual es la diferencia entre $git push -u origin master y $git push origin master?

Tags: git, git-push

Cuál es la diferencia al utilizar la bandera `-u` cuando hago un `$git push` para subir mi repositorio local a uno remoto? veo que hacen lo mismo, tanto
`$git push origin master` como `$git push -u origin master` he leido este [manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#git-push---set-upstream) pero no he podido entender bien el concepto

Answer (score 18, accepted):

La u significa *upstream* y se refiere al repositorio remoto principal al que harás `pull` y `push`, esta opción se utiliza una sola vez.

Cuando tienes mas de un repositorio remoto puedes utilizar esta opción para configurar uno de ellos como el principal... suponiendo que tienes un repo en BitBucket (bitbucket), otro en GitHub (origin) y otro en GitLab (gitlab) y quisieras utilizar GitHub (origin) como principal, tendrías que hacer `git push -u origin <branch>` y las siguientes veces al hacer solo `git push` lo hará a GitHub sin tener que especificar el repositorio pero para los otros dos si tendrías que hacerlo, ej. `git push bitbucket <branch>` o `git push gitlab <branch>`. Igual si tienes un solo repositorio y quieres evitar estar escribiendo `git push origin <branch>` puedes utilizar esta opción y solo hacer `git push` las siguientes veces.

A esta opción también se le conoce como "argument-less git-pull/push (git-pull/push sin argumentos)"

Comment: Perfecto y muy bien explicado, entonces si hago la primera vez `git push origin <branch>` tendría que hacerlo siempre igual las siguientes veces?

Comment: No es necesario, puedes configurarlo después si quieres. También he visto muchos que utilizan esta opción `-u` cada vez que hacen `push` pero es algo innecesario.